# Displayed dropdown value is out of sync with underlying value after VBA error is raised

Tags: vba

I have a custom dropdown Ribbon control in an Excel add-in with associated callbacks to set a global variable equal to what the user has selected in the dropdown. However, if a VBA error is raised then the global variable is reset to null but the dropdown still shows the previously selected value.

For example, in the code below, if the user selects the `PROD` option in the dropdown and then runs the `RaiseError` routine then `MsgBox mCurrentEnv` will display `PROD`. However, when they run `RaiseError` a second time a blank value will be shown, as at this point `mCurrentEnv` will be null. However, the Ribbon dropdown will still be displaying the originally selected `PROD` value. How in this instance would I make sure the dropdown is in sync with what is actually in `mCurrentEnv`?

```
<dropDown id="EnvDropDown" label="Environment" getSelectedItemID="GetSelectedEnvironment" onAction="OnActionEnvironment">
    <item id="PROD" label="PROD" />
    <item id="UAT" label="UAT" />
</dropDown>
```

```
Public mCurrentEnv As Variant

Sub RaiseError()
    MsgBox mCurrentEnv
    Err.Raise 1000, , "Problem!"
End Sub

Sub GetSelectedEnvironment(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef itemID As Variant)
    itemID = mCurrentEnv
End Sub

Sub OnActionEnvironment(control As IRibbonControl, selectedID As String, selectedIndex As Integer)
    mCurrentEnv = selectedID
End Sub
```